# Difference between policy path "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role" and ""arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy

What difference between policies under the paths "aws:policy/service-role" and "aws:policy/aws-service-role"?

Is there any the logic behind this design?

Answer (score 4):

The AWS managed policies within the `aws-service-role` path are policies that be attached to a service-linked role only.

If you go to AWS Console -> IAM -> Policies, filter by AWS Managed Polices and start clicking on them, you'll notice the ones with the `aws-servive-role` path have a help label at the top that reads "This policy is linked to a service and used only with a service-linked role for that service. You cannot attach, detach, modify, or delete this policy.". There might be a way to filter down to the service-linked policies in the AWS Console or CLI when desribing policies other than inspecting the paths, but it alludes me right now.

You can see their usage described here 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html.

Here also is the blog post that describes what a service-linked role is https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/introducing-an-easier-way-to-delegate-permissions-to-aws-services-service-linked-roles/. Basically these are roles that can only be assumed by a specific service type.

The AWS managed policies in the `service-role` path are policies that can be attached to any role including "normal/basic" roles. These types of roles can be assumed by users, EC2 instances, or anywhere else roles are assumed.

For example you could give someone permission to attach a linked-service role that has the policy `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/aws-service-role/AWSLambdaReplicator` attached which is only attachable to a linked-role linked to the Lambda service. They would be able to use this role in the Lambda execution role, but they would not be able to use this role with another service like EC2 or an IAM user. This supports an admin allowing users to assign out permissions to new resources that users spins up (a new Lambda) that that the admin trusts the linked AWS service to use, but don't want to allow that user to access directly through their user account or give them to other custom applications running in AWS.